# how to open a popup window and return values to the parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

how to open a popup window and return values to the parent page

i.e passing value fom popup window to parent form.

(The child window contain textbox with a button. Once the value entered in the textbox the value entered should be updated in parent window from child window)

in asp.net web application using C# ... any suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to achieve this affect I use the [JQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).  If you take a look at the ModalForm example in the link, it describes this sort of functionality.

This does depend on you're clients having Javascript enabled, but circumvents the whole issue with popup blockers.

If you want to do this the old way, popping up a new window by using window.ShowModalDialog and passing the values back to the original form [is explained here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fvolking/ModalPopupInASP.NET11262005000152AM/ModalPopupInASP.NET.aspx).